# Triggers: football team exercise issues

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have some trouble in doing triggers
I am doing some exercises for the university, and I prefer to test myself in a real mysql db.

The exercise is the following
The table schema is:

```
Result ( <b>Day, Home-Team, Visiting-Team</b>, Goal-Home, Goal-Visiting )
Ranking ( <b>Day, Team</b>, Points )
```

The exercise ask to define a trigger with the next rule
When I insert a tuple in the table Result, if Goal-Home > Goal-Visiting I must write two tuples in the table Ranking: one of the winner team and the other for the loser.
I clarify it with an example
Team A and B, in the day D, had a result of G_A vs G_B, so I must write 2 tuples in Ranking with this rules
If G_A > G_B i must write (D, A, 3) and (D, B, 0)
If G_A = G_B i must write (D, A, 1) and (D, B, 1)
If G_A < G_B i must write (D, A, 0) and (D, B, 3)


I have tested this code on my mysql db, but it doesn't work (i made some attempts)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insertRankValues 
AFTER INSERT ON Result
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.Goal-Home > NEW.Goal-Visiting 
INSERT INTO Ranking VALUES ( NEW.Day, NEW.Home-Team, 3);
INSERT INTO Ranking VALUES ( NEW.Day, NEW.Visiting-Team, 0);
END IF;
IF NEW.Goal-Home < NEW.Goal-Visiting 
INSERT INTO Ranking VALUES ( NEW.Day, NEW.Home-Team, 0);
INSERT INTO Ranking VALUES ( NEW.Day, NEW.Visiting-Team, 3);
END IF;
IF NEW.Goal-Home = NEW.Goal-Visiting 
INSERT INTO Ranking VALUES ( NEW.Day, NEW.Home-Team, 1);
INSERT INTO Ranking VALUES ( NEW.Day, NEW.Visiting-Team, 1);
END IF;
END; //
```

Do you have some suggestions?Why it doesn't work?
Thank you in advance for your patience!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use quotes '`' for columns like Goal-Home because '-' isn't allowed symbol.
So try to use 
    NEW.`Goal-Home`

Comment: or better yet, get into the habit of not using fields names that use characters like - or spaces or db keywords.

Comment: Agree but sometimes table scheme is legacy. :)

Comment: That's true and he should know this. But it is better to start with good habits.